# when a JFrame is minimized setState(JFrame.ICONIFIED) but where to write to code of event when user restores it from taskbar

Tags: java, netbeans, maximize

when user click on minimize my program minimizes two frames, and they both show differently in taskbar, but I want both of them to be restored for view on the screen when user clicks on either of them in the taskbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two `JFrame`'s are in `Frame.ICONIFIED` state (minimized) - when one of them is restored to `Frame.NORMAL` state the other also gets the normal state. This is achieved by implementing the `java.awt.event.WindowStateListener` for both the frames. Here is the demo program:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class TwoJframes implements WindowStateListener {
    private JFrame frame;
    private JFrame frame2;
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        new TwoJframes().gui();
    }
    private void gui() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("JFrame 1");
        JButton button = new JButton("Show Frame 2");
        button.addActionListener(e -> showAnotherFrame());
        frame.addWindowStateListener(this);
        frame.add(button);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setSize(250, 100);        
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    private void showAnotherFrame() {
        frame2 = new JFrame();
        frame2.setTitle("JFrame 2");
        frame2.addWindowStateListener(this);
        frame2.add(new JLabel("2nd frame"));
        frame2.setSize(250, 100);
        frame2.setLocation(300, 300);
        frame2.setVisible(true);
    }
    // This is the WindowStateListener's implementation method
    @Override public void windowStateChanged(WindowEvent e) {
        JFrame f = (JFrame) e.getSource();
        if (f == frame) {
            if ((frame.getExtendedState() == Frame.NORMAL) && 
                    (frame2.getExtendedState() == Frame.ICONIFIED)) {
                frame2.setExtendedState(Frame.NORMAL);
            }
        }
        if (f == frame2) {
            if ((frame2.getExtendedState() == Frame.NORMAL) && 
                    (frame.getExtendedState() == Frame.ICONIFIED)) {
                frame.setExtendedState(Frame.NORMAL);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, Prasad thanks for this code. I'm quite close in doing so. But I have one problem. See I already have two JFrames designed using netbeans drag and drop feature. I worte your code in new class but where do I call the methods of this class? or how to link it to other JFrames I have? please thanks.

Comment: So what is the issue? The two jframes are to be opened from a main class and this main class implements the _WindowStateListener_.

Comment: Okay Listen,
When I run the program I make one Jframe Visible, when users click on some button I make other Jframe visible too. I have a button in first Jframe which on Mousepress ICONFIES both Jframes,But i don't know where to create event which will set both of there states to NORMAL when user selects either one of them from taskbar.

Comment: Did you implement the listener interface and the override _windowStateChanged_ method?

Comment: Thanks Prasad, I did something with it and it works fine now for me.